# Extension of local diffeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space where $X$ is a manifold and $\widetilde{X}$ its metric completion. Further let $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ be a local diffeomorphism.

Can $f$ be extended to $\widetilde{X}\xrightarrow{\widetilde{f}}Y$, and if so do we have fruther information (e.g. uniqueness, structure)?

**Edit**

In my case, $Y$ is a Riemannian manifold $(Y,g)$ and the distance $d$ on $X$ is the one induced by the pullback metric $f^*g$.

It appears that $f$ can be extended if and only if $f$ is Cauchy-continuous. I believe this should give me the existence and uniqueness of the extension.

Comment: Think about $X=(0,1)$ with the standard metric and $f$ a diffeomorphism $X\to {\mathbb R}$. Does $f$ extend? You should read about uniformly continuous maps.

Comment: What is $Y?\,\,$

Comment: @zhw. I have edited my question.